# ionic error during processing of action! Attempting to revert

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project for the Android platform, to run  "ionic build android" or ionic emulate android" displays the below message:

Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Error: Uh oh!
Invalid Version: undefined

I have several installed sdk API 16 - API 23
Ionic 1.7.10
Cordova 5.4.1
OS X El Capitan 10.11

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it reverting to an older version.
npm install -g cordova@5.4.0

Comment: Thanks @Andrés!! There must be a bug in the latest cordova release. Your solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Better solution is to remove android platform and add it again:

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```